# How to rewrite URLs in php5?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Hi I want to rewrite my site URLs. Now I am using PHP 5 for development. I tried with the following .htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule   ^(.*)/(.*).html$ $1.php?code=$2 [L]
RewriteRule   ^(.*).html$ $1.php [L]
```

The URL without argument is working, but the first one shows some problems. It redirects to the page, but the page styles are missing whatever value I pass for code.
Why is it happening? Is there any option for rewriting URLs using PHP5?

Comment: By the way, mod_rewrite is an Apache server module, it has nothing to do with PHP

Comment: What do you mean with "the page styles are missing"?

Comment: The "(.*).html$" part should be "(.*)\.html$" or the pattern would match also "examplehtml" (instead of matching only strings ending with ".html").

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you redirect to 'folder/file.html' all of your relative links will be messed up. It will be looking for 'css/style.css' in 'folder/css/style.css' instead.

You can either use absolute links i.e. 'www.example.com/css/style.css' or rewrite your link paths as well.

```
RewriteRule   ^(.+)/css/(.+)$ css/$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you talk about css styling, I think it might be because you're entering a new subdirectory, and the style.css isn't there but in the main directory. It's about relative paths, try using a absolute path ("www.web.com/style.css")

Answer (score 1):

You have your URL in $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
which you can parse in your php script and include required file.
In your example 'REQUEST_URI' will be '/folder/file.html'. So you can leave only this RewriteRule   ^(.*).html$ $1.php

Answer (score 1):

in html head you set `<base href="http://mysite.com/"/>` before including css, js & etc.